# RollingFileAppender sometimes my service stoppes to generate log files and stoppes to write to the log file

Tags: c#, log4net

I use RollingFileAppender and I have a strange problem: sometimes my service stoppes to generate log files and stopps to write to the log file if it is open by the text editor.

What I am doing wrong?

Here is how I configure the

```
PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout
    {ConversionPattern = "%date %-5level [%logger] [%-4thread]: %exception%message%newline"};
layout.ActivateOptions();
RollingFileAppender fileAppender = new RollingFileAppender {
   AppendToFile = append,
   File = traceFileName,
   MaxSizeRollBackups = maxSizeRollBackups,
   DatePattern = "_dd.MM.yyyy",
   LockingModel = new FileAppender.MinimalLock(),
  Layout = layout,
  RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Date,
};
fileAppender.ActivateOptions();
log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure(fileAppender);
```

Comment: Attach the debugger, find out what it is doing.